# scrapy-splash doesn't return all of the data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to create a scraper that can scrape data from a certain website, example:

https://www.spicejet.com/search?from=BOM&to=BLR&tripType=1&departure=2022-04-20&adult=1&child=0&infant=0&currency=USD&redirectTo=/

The problem is that it scrapes only some of the data, but what I really need (the flight's details) isn't returned.

I need this div element: <div id="react-root">
which contains a lot of divs with the flight's details, but when I use scrapy-splash I only get this div element without his chlidren elements - that store the data.

I know there are a few similar questions, but non of the solutions helped.

that's the code:

```
class SpiceJetSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "spiceJet"       
    flight_search_results = []
    custom_settings = {
        'BOT_NAME' : 'flightsCadgerScrapy',

        'SPIDER_MODULES' : ['flightsCadgerScrapy.spiders'],
        'NEWSPIDER_MODULE' : 'flightsCadgerScrapy.spiders',

        
        'SPLASH_URL' : 'http://localhost:8050',

        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
            'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
            'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
        },

        'SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
            'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
        },

        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS' : 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',

        'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE' : 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
    }

    

    def __init__(self, flight_search_request):
        self.url = 'https://www.spicejet.com/search?from=BOM&to=BLR&tripType=1&departure=2022-04-20&adult=1&child=0&infant=0&currency=USD&redirectTo=/'

    def start_requests(self):   
        yield SplashRequest(self.url, self.parse, args={'wait': 6})

    def parse(self, response):
        flight_obj = response.css('div').getall()
        self.flight_search_results.append(flight_obj)
        
        return self.flight_search_results
```

The response I get contains a list of divs, but the one I need is empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way of loading javascript heavy websites is to use `scrapy-playwright`. It is simple and easier to set up than `scrapy-splash`. Read more about its use from [here](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright).

See below sample code showing you how you might use it to obtain the rendered html of the page which you can then parse to obtain the required data.

```py
import scrapy


class SpiceJetSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "spiceJet"
    custom_settings = dict(
        DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS={
            "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
        },
        TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.spicejet.com/search?from=BOM&to=BLR&tripType=1&departure=2022-04-20&adult=1&child=0&infant=0&currency=USD&redirectTo=/'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'playwright': True})

    def parse(self, response):
        # do all the parsing you need of the response here
        yield {
            "html": response.text
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this solution, but I get this error: ERROR: Loading "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler" for scheme "https"
Traceback (most recent call last):.......
Exception: The installed reactor (twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor) does not match the requested one (twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor)

Comment: Update the scrapy version to 2.6.1 or move the custom settings to the settings file

Comment: Now showing another error:AttributeError: 'ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler' object has no attribute 'contexts'

Comment: by the way, I'm using CrawlerProcess to run the spider, if that matters.